# How to see what's going on during shutdown

Tags: shutdown, system

Since a few weeks, Ubuntu freezes almost everytime when I shut it down.

I know it because the shutdown animation stops and nothing is responsive: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> or <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Syst</kbd>+<kbd>reisub</kbd> don't make any difference.

I have tried to look at various log files in `/var/log` but only INFO level message are logged.

My hope to solve this problem would be to do a verbose shutdown, one where I could see what's going on, and so what's causing the problem, so I could start solving it.

Therefore, as the title suggest it. Is there a way to see what's going on during shutdown? I could even go to the extreme of doing a step-by-step shutdown if this is the only way.

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: I finally found out what was going on. I get a CPU soft lock-up between 2 process on shutdown: umount and java. Java is actually the Crashplan backup application. I've found out that they don't do proper shutdown (they're using init scripts but none for runlevels 0 or 6). The following fixed the problem: `sudo update-rc.d -f crashplan remove ; sudo update-rc.d crashplan defaults 60 30`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Temporarily disable the slash screen

You can temporarily disable the splash screen and "quiet" mode by editing the boot command in GRUB:

1. Reboot and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> as the computer turns on. The GRUB menu should appear:

   [image: GRUB menu]
2. Press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit the command for the first entry, then use the keyboard to delete the words `quiet splash`:

   [image: GRUB command editor]
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to boot.

This setting will last until the next reboot.

### Permanently disable the slash screen

You can make the change permanent by modifying `/etc/default/grub`. Comment out this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

and add this one:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
```

Run `sudo update-grub` and then reboot to make the changes take effect.

Warning: If you mess up this file your computer may not be able to boot up again. Let someone here know if you're not sure how to make the modification.

Comment: OK, i'll do that. Perhaps instead of modifying it for good, I can just edit the grub prompt live, so if I make a mistake, I just have to restart the computer and I'm fine again.

Comment: That is an excellent idea.

Comment: I've done several start and shutdown, and your trick is exactly what I was looking for. Though sadly for me, my computer refuses to crash now that I can control it ;-) Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just so that it's mentioned here: You can 'edit grub live' by holding down shift while booting up and pressing `e` having selected the entry you want to modify.

Comment: Or you could just simply push the home button to see the messages.

Answer (score 0):

When shutting down, enter tty1 by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, and then from there shut down the desktop manager.

```
sudo service gdm stop
```

or if you're using 11.10, then

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

then shut down the computer by running

```
sudo halt
```

Now you should see all the infos.