# System doesn't boot unless I hit enter

Tags: 11.04, boot, plymouth

I'm trying to remove a ~40 seconds pause that happens when my Ubuntu machine starts.

During this pause, all I see is a magenta rectangle (approx 80% of screen size) over a black background.

The gap is clearly visible on my bootchart (not using an IMG tag here because the image is too high):

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18558160/syrius-natty-20110512-1.png

I also see a gap on my syslog. It seems to be related with the "video device" (I've got an NVIDIA).

```
...
May 12 23:15:14 syrius kernel: [    1.544436] TCP reno registered
May 12 23:15:14 syrius kernel: [    1.544447] UDP hash table entries: 4096 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
May 12 23:15:14 syrius kernel: [    1.544491] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 4096 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
May 12 23:15:14 syrius kernel: [    1.544593] NET: Registered protocol family 1
May 12 23:15:14 syrius kernel: [   42.870179] pci 0000:06:00.0: Boot video device
May 12 23:15:14 syrius kernel: [   42.870222] PCI: CLS 64 bytes, default 64
May 12 23:15:14 syrius kernel: [   42.871588] PCI-DMA: Disabling AGP.
May 12 23:15:14 syrius kernel: [   42.871697] PCI-DMA: aperture base @ c4000000 size 65536 KB
```

What can I do to fix this? It didn't happen on Ubuntu 10.10.

I've done some more tests. It seems that the boot sequence requires some sort of input while booting (?) It turns out that it'll not boot until I press enter (the magenta rectangle stays in the screen forever unless you press enter)

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Try [temporarily disabling the splash screen](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6122/how-to-see-whats-going-on-during-shutdown/6128#6128) to reveal the underlying prompt.

Comment: I had a similar issue on my laptop - I had to add "noapic" to my grub entry - does this work for you?

Comment: I get something a bit like this too since upgrading to natty. I don't think it's a prompt - moving the mouse seems to have the same effect(!). Probably an interrupt problem. Nvidia also.

Comment: Could you post your dmesg? For me it's better to see the whole dmesg output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've noticed that since last week (around 2011-07-11 / 2011-07-16) an update seems to have fixed this issue. My computer "timeout" has been automatically reduced from 150 seconds to 5. It's still visible, but it isn't an issue any more.

I'm closing down this question.

Answer (score 1):

Or press e when you see the grub boot message, go to the line that starts with "linux", cursor to the end of the line and delete "splash" and "quiet", then Ctrl-X to continue the boot process.  This will allow you to see what is happening during boot.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

try editing you /lib/plymouth/themes/"your current theme"/mdv.script
and make sure the background is set to a "Z" value of negative 1000 just in case it is blocking a password prompt box or something.

that part is usually at the beginning if the script where the image is loaded

```
background.sprite = SpriteNew();
background.sprite.SetImage(background.image);
background.sprite.SetPosition(Window.GetX(), Window.GetY(), -1000);
```

you can also check if the prompt box has an opacity of 0 making it invisible if that is the case change it to 1 and after you are done with editing the plymouth theme do a 
`sudo update-initramfs -u`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on a Fedora box I was using, turned out to be a Samba mount that I added to my fstab but forgot to add a password, so it was waiting for me to enter a password before finishing the boot.

You can always try pressing ESC to see what's being output behind the rectangle?

Comment: thanks for your answer but no, pressing ESC doesn't show anything different than pressing any other keys.