# How do I diagnose Hang on Shutdown?

Tags: shutdown, freeze, log, sysrq

Since one or two months ago, my laptop with ubuntu 12.10x64 hangs **during shutdown**. There's just a black screen, no harddisk activity, **it justs sits there**. I feel it happens near the end of a normal shutdown cycle, judging from time elapsed.

Only resolution is **hard power-off** (holding power key for several seconds) - neither Ctrl-Alt-Backspace (which normally works, I have it switched on in Settings) nor Ctrl-Alt-Del help, nor can I get into a text console with Ctrl-Alt-F1.

**How do I diagnose that**? It does not happen on every shutdown, but often enough to be annoying (as it forces a diskcheck on reboot, of course).

**Which log files** can tell me what's going wrong? More or less blindly searching in the sys log viewer reminds me of needles in a haystack.

I imagine I could pinpoint the time it happens via log timestamps, but **how do I read timestamps** like e.g. in `kern.log`: `[36169.146130]`? How do I get this human-readable?

Lastly, a bit of a btw, I've never managed to execute an Alt-Sysrq-REISUB to force a cleaner shutdown, but that's probably because I'm on a laptop, PrintScr is only accessible via an `Fn` key, and I'm not sure of the exact key sequence I need. Is there a **"harmless" but user-visible magic command** I could practice this with (during normal operation), so I can find out how to do a REISUB next time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to shutdown without the splash screen, and from the command line to see what's going on. First you need to disable splash via GRUB (See [verbose shutdown](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6122/how-to-see-whats-going-on-during-shutdown))

Boot and hold SHIFT to enter grub. Press while over the linux entry to edit it. Then go to the kernel line (press END to go to the end of the line) and remove the "quiet" and "splash" arguments. In fact, for this one test skip out the GUI al together and add the argument "text". (Without this you can get to the command line with CTRL+ALT+F1)

Login, then type:

```
sudo shutdown -v -h now
```

(-v for verbose, -h for halt.)

Kernel log files in /var/log/kern.log should contain human readable time stamps. Open them with the log file viewer

```
gnome-system-log
```

(File>open) And you should see the human readable time stamp on the left. If you still don't see the human readable ones, this guy [made some python/perl scripts](http://linuxaria.com/article/how-to-make-dmesg-timestamp-human-readable?lang=en) to parse them.

Comment: The problem is I can't reproduce it at will, it doesn't happen on every shutdown. But that question about `quiet splash` is gold, I'll remove those and wait for a hanging shutdown..

Comment: This answer has interesting info. It does not anwers all of the OP's questions, though (as is clear from the "hope you get the issue resolved soon." remark). Can you expand, James?

Comment: Sorry, I'd mainly gone for the rest of the question. I don't know of anything that could cause this because I'm not the most experienced linux user, however I was just throwing what I know about logging in for what it's worth to help the asker because they were asking for info on how to see shutdown logs.

Eitherway, I added some more info answering the time stamp question.

Comment: Ok, so I have activated logging on shutdown, just haven't experienced a hang on shutdown since then. I'll accept this answer.

Comment: `man shutdown` does not show a -v option for me (using Ubuntu).  Does it really exist?

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer your questions in order of increasing difficulty / detail.

> Which log files can tell me what's going wrong?

Sorry to be vague, but it really depends.  There can be many root causes for various types of hang.  For example:  GPU driver bugs, running out of memory, disk or swap space, fork bombs & CPU hogs, kernel bugs, shutdown process hangs, etc...

You can narrow down the list of things to look at by knowing more about the symptoms and particular problem (e.g. Shutdown-specific hangs), and which subsystems, processes, and logs are involved with that particular problem area.
For example with shutdown-specific hangs, look at:

- Kernel logs (`dmesg`, `/var/log/kern.log`, `journalctl --dmesg --boot[=[ID][±offset]|all]`)
- [Plymouth](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Plymouth/) logs (`/var/boot/log`)

  - [ArchLinux has great docs on Plymouth](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/plymouth)
- SystemD (specifically: [`systemd-shutdown`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-poweroff.service.html))  (`journalctl --boot[=[ID][±offset]|all]_PID=1`, `journalctl --list-boots`  for IDs, and sometimes `/var/log/syslog`)
- [Finalrd](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/man1/finalrd.1.html) (Should also output to kernel's ringbuffer `dmesg`)

> how do I read timestamps like e.g. in kern.log: [36169.146130]? How do I get this human-readable?

To look at kernel logs (for current boot) with human readable timestamps:

```
sudo dmesg -H
sudo journalctl -b 0 -xn10000 --dmesg
```

To look at last boot kernel logs (current boot `0` minus `1`):

```
sudo journalctl -b -1 -xn10000 --dmesg
```

The timestamps in the kernel log are in seconds since last boot.  You'll notice in the plain `sudo dmesg` output that the timestamp always starts at `[    0.000000]` with the line `Linux version x.x.x-x`, and increases from there.  The reason the timestamps are done this way by default is because many things happen in very quick succession during the Linux kernel boot.  The speed of the CPU is able to execute many commands within microseconds.  At this level of time granularity, printing the full date / timestamp would be rather pointless.

You can always ask `dmesg` to print in human readable output with `-H` / `--human` flag, which is an alias for  `--color`, `--reltime` and `--pager`.

> How do I diagnose that?

There are a few ways to debug shutdown, freeze and hang problems.  The log files to look at will depend on where the root cause of the issue lies:

1. Kernel issues (GPU or other drivers, kernel bugs)

   - Check `dmesg` output near the end of the boot where it is hanging
   - Either turn off splash screen by removing `quiet splash` boot parameters, or [toggle text-based boot](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Plymouth) by presssing right arrow `→` or `Escape`

     - If you have `plymouth` splash screen running (`quiet splash` is in `/etc/default/grub` by default)
     - Run: `sudo update-grub` after changing this file to apply the changes into the generated `/boot/grub` configs.
   - If using SystemD, you can drop a script to execute on shutdown here: `/usr/lib/systemd/system-shutdown/debug.sh`

     - [This tip is listed in the FreeDesktop.org page: SystemD Debugging](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Debugging/#index2h1)
     - Set and boot with the debug options:

       ```
       systemd.log_level=debug systemd.log_target=kmsg log_buf_len=1M printk.devkmsg=on enforcing=0
       ```
     - The recommended example script to debug kernel shutdown issues is:

       ```
       #!/bin/sh
       mount -o remount,rw /
       dmesg > /shutdown-log.txt
       mount -o remount,ro /
       ```
     - You may want to replace `dmesg` with `dmesg --human --nopager` for human-readable timestamps.
     - **Note:** that the timestamps will be shown once every few seconds, and the rest of the quick boot messages below each full timestamp will still have nanosecond resolution denoted like: `+0.002567` for example.
   - Reboot, and look for timeouts logged in the resulting file: `/shutdown-log.txt`

Finally, the [FreeDesktop.org HangDiagnosis Page](https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/HangDiagnosis.html) has some helpful information about the different levels of hang that you may encounter.  It also lists some other methods for extracting Linux kernel messages which are more advanced because they may require two computers (`netconsole`, SSH), or an IEEE1394 Firewire connection (`firescope`), or else an RS-232 or other serial console.  SSH is also a slightly easier option I didn't list, because SSH gets killed during shutdown, it isn't always available depending on the hang level, and it also requires two computers (setup OpenSSH server on the target, remote SSH into it using another computer as client).

2. SystemD Debug Shell

   - [See Fedora's docs on SystemD debug-shell](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd_early_debug-shell)
   - Follow the instructions to enable the debug shell, then press `Ctrl+Alt+F9` to switch to it.
   - Note that if you do this during shutdown, you could affect files being in use on the root or `/oldroot` pivoted root mountpoint.  Just be aware that you can cause messages to appear that otherwise wouldn't, and they may be a red herring (or [Heisenbug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug)... since you're causing them by being the observer and holding open a shell during shutdown poking at things).
   - **Be sure to disable this when you're done!**  When enabled, it leaves a security risk where anyone with physical access does not need the root password:

     ```
     systemctl disable debug-shell
     ```
3. Finalrd Hook Scripts

   - See: `man finalrd` (or [Ubuntu's docs here](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/man1/finalrd.1.html))
   - To use this method, drop a script into `/etc/finalrd/` with any name as long as it ends in `.finalrd` suffix.
   - You can combine this method with the " `/shutdown-log.txt`" method from #1 above to view the output later.  (This can be helpful if the scrollback buffer is not enabled during shutdown... `Shift+PgUp` doesn't always work).
   - **Note:** that you'll have to craft the script in such a way as to "bootstrap" any binaries you wish to run in the script during the `setup` phase hook.

     - What this means is that because during shutdown the `/` root mountpoint is remounted as `/oldroot`
     - In other words: SystemD init changes into a new location and moves the old root mounted filesystem into another place (a.k.a. "[pivot root](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pivot_root.2.html)")
     - Because of this, any binaries you'd expect to be in your shell script's `PATH` are not there anymore.
     - **For Example:**: To bootstrap a few tools, show what processes are using files in `/` root, and show mountpoints, make a script like this:

       ```
       #!/bin/sh
       # SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0-only
       # Copy executables during finalrd setup phase
       if [ "$1" = "setup" ]
       then
           . /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hook-functions
           copy_exec /usr/bin/lsof
           copy_exec /usr/bin/mount
           copy_exec /usr/bin/grep

           exit 0
       fi

       echo '------------ WHAT ELSE IS USING OLDROOT? ------------'
       echo ''
       # List everything except filter out kworker tasks
       lsof . | grep -v kworker

       echo '------------ WHAT IS MOUNTED? ------------'
       mount

       exit 0
       ```

> I've never managed to execute an Alt-Sysrq-REISUB to force a cleaner shutdown, but that's probably because I'm on a laptop.

Yes, you're probably correct.  Many modern keyboards no longer have the `SysRq` key... much to the displeasure of Linux users and kernel developers. 
I'd suggest finding a secondary keyboard that has the `SysRq` key.  I use an older PS/2 keyboard which I leave plugged into the back of a HTPC, and routed the cable into a drawer under the TV stand.  You can probably find such a keyboard at a garage sale, or for a very affordable price online.  With a laptop, you'll need a USB to PS/2 connector, or a native USB keyboard that has the `SysRq` key.

**Why PS/2?:** These old ports are not common to find on laptops, however modern PCs still often have them.  If you can use a PS/2 port for the magic `SysRq` key combos, do it!  The reason is simple: [PS/2 is more reliable](https://www.makeuseof.com/what-is-a-ps2-port-why-computers-still-have-them/), while USB can often fail to operate during hangs due to the nature of polling.  PS/2 is handled at the interrupt level and can often pre-empt other tasks, [which is especially helpful on Real-Time Linux kernels](https://bootlin.com/doc/training/preempt-rt/preempt-rt-slides.pdf).  Unfortunately for laptops USB is often the only option, and USB to PS/2 adapters still are presented to the system as standard USB HIDs and get polled.

When things hang, I open the drawer with that PS/2 keyboard and use `Alt+SysRq+` `r`, `e`, `i`, `s`, `u`, `b` in that order, maybe pressing each a few times while watching kernel logs to see that the kernel is responding to the commands.  I've noticed with some kernel driver hangs, the kernel is keeping the CPU very busy and sometimes the keystrokes don't trigger a response the first time.

> Is there a "harmless" but user-visible magic command I could practice this with (during normal operation), so I can find out how to do a REISUB next time?

Most of the commands are pretty harmless in the grand scheme of things, except if you value your data and press `Alt+SysRq+b` before syncing all disk caches to disk with `Alt+SysRq+s`.  Most of the commands are usually disabled by default via the `/proc/sys/kernel/sysrq` mask bits.  If you know that one of these key combinations is masked, you can press it all you want and the kernel will just output this message:

> sysrq: This sysrq operation is disabled.

So to leverage this, just check `cat /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq` output.  On Ubuntu it's set to: `244`.  So on those systems the `Alt+SysRq+n` command is masked:

```
256 = 0x100 - allow nicing of all RT tasks
```

| Command | Function |
| --- | --- |
| n | Used to make RT tasks nice-able |

Source: [Linux Kernel Docs: Magic SysRq Key](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysrq.html)

So on a system with that bitmask, I can press `Alt+SysRq+n` all I want and the kernel just says that operation is disabled.  That's probably the most reliable no-op way to test that the kernel is responding to the `SysRq` key combo.

- In one terminal, run:

  ```
  sudo dmesg -H --nopager --follow
  ```
- Press your disabled `SysRq` key command (e.g.: `Alt+SysRq+n`)
- Look for the "`sysrq: This sysrq operation is disabled.`" output.

If the kernel doesn't respond, then either:

- `CONFIG_MAGIC_SYSRQ` kernel option was turned off during compile-time
- Keyboard does not have `SysRq` key, isn't connected, or isn't sending proper keycode
- Kernel is hung at "level 8" or above (as per [FreeDesktop's HangDiagnosis](https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/HangDiagnosis.html) classification system)

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem.  Disabling 3D Acceleration in Bios *seems* to fix the problem.

Press F1 or F2 on start up (or on the system settings in the grub) and disable 3D acceleration.  Let me know if this fixes the problem.  I have tried three or four shutdowns with no problem, but the problem might return.