# Dual boot Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS, with /Root on SSD and /Home on HDD. nVidia graphics. It takes ten minutes to shut down. Why?

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, hard-drive, shutdown, ssd

Sometimes my laptop shuts down normally but on six out of ten occasions it will take ten minutes to shut down. The screen sits with the Ubuntu Studio logo and a turning wheel. On pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>, the display shows:

```
Reached target Shutdown.
Reached target Final step.
Finished Power-Off.
Reached target Power-Off.
```

All as expected, then after a while it goes into a repeated routine of

```
systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices - timed out, issuing SIGKILL to PID 2290
```

Then many lines such as:

```
nvme nvme0: I/O 510 QID 8 timeout, reset controller
Waiting for process: systemd-journal, (sd-sync)
```

The machine goes through several cycles of error messages on several pages before eventually shutting down.

I've tried Alt SysRq REISUB, but the machine won't reboot without a hard power off first, when the HDD can be heard to skid to a stop, which sets my teeth on edge.

Forcing a power down during the error messages causes the same HDD/teeth problem.

Booting is normal and quick.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Edit: The thread [How do I diagnose Hang on Shutdown?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236476/how-do-i-diagnose-hang-on-shutdown) does not answer my question. Unlike in that post I can see shutdown activity simply by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> while the shutdown splash screen is on. I can also hear HDD activity.

I managed to photo the screen moments before the laptop eventually shut down:

[image: Shutdown messages]

Examples of the messages are such as these:

```
[641.546916] Buffer I/O error on dev nvme0n1p6, logical block 13...
and
[641.550604] EXT4-fs warning (device nvme0n1p6): ext4_end_bio:30...
and
[641.554511] JBDZ: Error -5 detected when updating journal super...
```

Device nvme0n1 is the SSD, p6 is where the / is installed. So the error is somewhere there. Could it be a faulty SSD?

Edit: From `/var/log/syslog` This is a normal shut down. It occurs at 12:21:02. The machine is then rebooted at 12:22:44.

```
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1240]: Stopping Studio - session monitor...
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: unattended-upgrades.service: Succeeded.
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: Stopping Session c2 of user dg.
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: Removed slice system-modprobe.slice.
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: Stopped target Bluetooth.
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: Stopped target Graphical Interface.
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: Stopped target Multi-User System.
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: Stopped target Login Prompts.
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: Stopped target Sound Card.
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: Stopped target Timers.
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: anacron.timer: Succeeded.
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: Stopped Trigger anacron every hour.
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: apt-daily-upgrade.timer: Succeeded.
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: Stopped Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: apt-daily.timer: Succeeded.
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: Stopped Daily apt download activities.
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: e2scrub_all.timer: Succeeded.
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: Stopped Periodic ext4 Online Metadata Check for All Filesystems.
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: fstrim.timer: Succeeded.
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: Stopped Discard unused blocks once a week.
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: fwupd-refresh.timer: Succeeded.
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: Stopped Refresh fwupd metadata regularly.
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: logrotate.timer: Succeeded.
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: Stopped Daily rotation of log files.
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: man-db.timer: Succeeded.
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: Stopped Daily man-db regeneration.
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: motd-news.timer: Succeeded.
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: Stopped Message of the Day.
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer: Succeeded.
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: Stopped Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: systemd-rfkill.socket: Succeeded.
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: Closed Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status /dev/rfkill Watch.
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery ModemManager[931]: <info>  Caught signal, shutting down...
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: Stopping Modem Manager...
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery at-spi-bus-launcher[1370]: X connection to :0 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: Stopping Accounts Service...
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: Stopping ACPI event daemon...
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery xfce4-notifyd[1525]: xfce4-notifyd: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery xfce4-screensav[1377]: xfce4-screensaver: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery NetworkManager[750]: <info>  [1602933662.2539] modem-manager: ModemManager no longer available
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery ModemManager[931]: <info>  ModemManager is shut down
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: Stopping Save/Restore Sound Card State...
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1240]: xfce4-notifyd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1240]: xfce4-notifyd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: automatic crash report generation...
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: Stopping Bluetooth service...
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: Stopping Manage, Install and Generate Color Profiles...
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: Stopping Regular background program processing daemon...
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: Stopping Make remote CUPS printers available locally...
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: Stopping Getty on tty1...
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB...
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery bluetoothd[744]: Terminating
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: disk temperature monitoring daemon…
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: Stopping Make remote CUPS printers available locally...
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: Stopping Getty on tty1...
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB...
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery bluetoothd[744]: Terminating
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: disk temperature monitoring daemon...
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: Stopping irqbalance daemon...
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: Stopping Tool to automatically collect and submit kernel crash signatures...
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: Stopping Light Display Manager...
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: lm-sensors.service: Succeeded.
Oct 17 12:21:02 computery systemd[1]: Stopped Initialize hardware monitoring sensors.
Oct 17 12:22:44 computery systemd-modules-load[342]: Inserted module 'lp'
Oct 17 12:22:44 computery systemd-modules-load[342]: Inserted module 'ppdev'
Oct 17 12:22:44 computery systemd-modules-load[342]: Inserted module 'parport_pc'
Oct 17 12:22:44 computery systemd-modules-load[342]: Inserted module 'cuse'
Oct 17 12:22:44 computery systemd-sysctl[364]: Not setting net/ipv4/conf/all/promote_secondaries (explicit setting exists).
Oct 17 12:22:44 computery systemd-sysctl[364]: Not setting net/ipv4/conf/default/promote_secondaries (explicit setting exists).
Oct 17 12:22:44 computery systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
Oct 17 12:22:44 computery systemd[1]: Received SIGRTMIN+20 from PID 392 (plymouthd).
Oct 17 12:22:44 computery systemd[1]: Started Show Plymouth Boot Screen.
Oct 17 12:22:44 computery systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch being skipped.
Oct 17 12:22:44 computery systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Plymouth Directory Watch.
Oct 17 12:22:44 computery systemd[1]: Reached target Local Encrypted Volumes.
Oct 17 12:22:44 computery systemd[1]: Finished Flush Journal to Persistent Storage.
Oct 17 12:22:44 computery systemd-udevd[378]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v245'.
Oct 17 12:22:44 computery mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 2: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8"
Oct 17 12:22:44 computery mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 2 was not an MTP device
Oct 17 12:22:44 computery systemd-udevd[378]: ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Oct 17 12:22:44 computery systemd-udevd[393]: ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Oct 17 12:22:44 computery systemd[1]: Listening on Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status /dev/rfkill Watch.
Oct 17 12:22:44 computery systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status...
Oct 17 12:22:44 computery systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch being skipped.
Oct 17 12:22:44 computery systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Set Up Additional Binary Formats being skipped.
Oct 17 12:22:44 computery systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in File System Check on Root Device being skipped.
Oct 17 12:22:44 computery systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Rebuild Hardware Database being skipped.
Oct 17 12:22:44 computery systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Platform Persistent Storage Archival being skipped.
Oct 17 12:22:44 computery systemd[1]: Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status.
Oct 17 12:22:44 computery systemd[1]: Found device KINGSTON SA2000M8250G SYSTEM.
Oct 17 12:22:44 computery systemd[1]: Starting File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/7E72-A7B1...
Oct 17 12:22:44 computery systemd[1]: Started File System Check Daemon to report status.
Oct 17 12:22:44 computery systemd[1]: Created slice system-systemd\x2dbacklight.slice.
Oct 17 12:22:44 computery systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:intel_backlight...
Oct 17 12:22:44 computery systemd[1]: Finished Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:intel_backlight.
Oct 17 12:22:44 computery systemd-fsck[595]: fsck.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
Oct 17 12:22:44 computery systemd-fsck[595]: /dev/nvme0n1p1: 195 files, 8465/75776 clusters
Oct 17 12:22:44 computery systemd[1]: Finished File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/7E72-A7B1.
Oct 17 12:22:44 computery systemd[1]: Mounting /boot/efi...
Oct 17 12:22:44 computery systemd[1]: Mounted /boot/efi.
Oct 17 12:22:44 computery systemd-udevd[383]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v245'.
```

This happened when a shutdown took ten minutes or so. The final shutdown instruction is at 22:19:07 before the weirdness happens. The machine is rebooted the next day:

```
ct 16 21:34:02 computery systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Run anacron jobs being skipped.
Oct 16 22:10:01 computery avahi-daemon[739]: Withdrawing address record for 2a00:23c5:4d10:6401:ddde:4ce4:38e9:4076 on wlp0s20f3.
Oct 16 22:10:01 computery avahi-daemon[739]: Registering new address record for 2a00:23c5:4d10:6401:ddde:4ce4:38e9:4076 on wlp0s20f3.*.
Oct 16 22:10:01 computery avahi-daemon[739]: Registering new address record for fe80::3e85:8b16:60a3:de9a on wlp0s20f3.*.
Oct 16 22:10:04 computery systemd-resolved[723]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Oct 16 22:10:04 computery systemd-resolved[723]: message repeated 5 times: [ Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.]
Oct 16 22:10:20 computery avahi-daemon[739]: Withdrawing address record for 2a00:23c5:4d10:6401:ddde:4ce4:38e9:4076 on wlp0s20f3.
Oct 16 22:10:20 computery avahi-daemon[739]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::3e85:8b16:60a3:de9a on wlp0s20f3.
Oct 16 22:10:20 computery avahi-daemon[739]: Registering new address record for 2a00:23c5:4d10:6401:ddde:4ce4:38e9:4076 on wlp0s20f3.*.
Oct 16 22:10:23 computery systemd-resolved[723]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Oct 16 22:10:23 computery systemd-resolved[723]: message repeated 5 times: [ Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.]
Oct 16 22:10:24 computery wpa_supplicant[842]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-46 noise=9999 txrate=866700
Oct 16 22:17:01 computery CRON[3528]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Oct 16 22:19:06 computery kernel: [ 9806.939787] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
Oct 16 22:19:06 computery kernel: [ 9806.943051] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
Oct 16 22:19:06 computery kernel: [ 9806.943596] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
Oct 16 22:19:07 computery systemd[1254]: Stopping Studio - session monitor...
Oct 16 22:19:07 computery systemd[1]: unattended-upgrades.service: Succeeded.
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@Oct 17 11:50:17 computery systemd-modules-load[348]: Inserted module 'lp'
Oct 17 11:50:17 computery systemd-modules-load[348]: Inserted module 'ppdev'
Oct 17 11:50:17 computery systemd-modules-load[348]: Inserted module 'parport_pc'
Oct 17 11:50:17 computery systemd-modules-load[348]: Inserted module 'cuse'
Oct 17 11:50:17 computery systemd-sysctl[370]: Not setting net/ipv4/conf/all/promote_secondaries (explicit setting exists).
Oct 17 11:50:17 computery systemd-sysctl[370]: Not setting net/ipv4/conf/default/promote_secondaries (explicit setting exists).
Oct 17 11:50:17 computery systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
Oct 17 11:50:17 computery systemd[1]: Activated swap /swapfile.
Oct 17 11:50:17 computery systemd[1]: Reached target Swap.
Oct 17 11:50:17 computery systemd[1]: Received SIGRTMIN+20 from PID 387 (plymouthd).
Oct 17 11:50:17 computery systemd[1]: Started Show Plymouth Boot Screen.
Oct 17 11:50:17 computery systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch being skipped.
Oct 17 11:50:17 computery systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Plymouth Directory Watch.
Oct 17 11:50:17 computery kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 5.4.0-48-lowlatency (buildd@lcy01-amd64-010) (gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2)) #52-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Thu Sep 10 11:51:50 UTC 2020 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-48.52-lowlatency 5.4.60)
Oct 17 11:50:17 computery systemd[1]: Reached target Local Encrypted Volumes.
Oct 17 11:50:17 computery systemd[1]: Finished Flush Journal to Persistent Storage.
Oct 17 11:50:17 computery systemd-udevd[381]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v245'.
Oct 17 11:50:17 computery kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-48-lowlatency root=UUID=acfebebf-4250-42c6-91a5-0e02a43f7f9d ro quiet splash vt.handoff=1
Oct 17 11:50:17 computery mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 2: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8"
Oct 17 11:50:17 computery kernel: [    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
Oct 17 11:50:17 computery kernel: [    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
Oct 17 11:50:17 computery kernel: [    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
Oct 17 11:50:17 computery kernel: [    0.000000]   Hygon HygonGenuine
Oct 17 11:50:17 computery mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 2 was not an MTP device
Oct 17 11:50:17 computery kernel: [    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
Oct 17 11:50:17 computery systemd-udevd[381]: ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Oct 17 11:50:17 computery kernel: [    0.000000]   zhaoxin   Shanghai  
Oct 17 11:50:17 computery kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x001: 'x87 floating point registers'
Oct 17 11:50:17 computery kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x002: 'SSE registers'
```

Here is another `/syslog` from a slow shutdown.

```
Oct 17 16:14:16 computery NetworkManager[748]: <info>  [1602947656.2646] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Oct 17 16:14:16 computery whoopsie[1253]: [16:14:16] The default IPv4 route is: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
Oct 17 16:14:16 computery whoopsie[1253]: [16:14:16] Not a paid data plan: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
Oct 17 16:14:16 computery whoopsie[1253]: [16:14:16] Found usable connection: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
Oct 17 16:14:16 computery whoopsie[1253]: [16:14:16] online
Oct 17 16:14:16 computery wpa_supplicant[835]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-29 noise=9999 txrate=26000
Oct 17 16:14:17 computery systemd-resolved[722]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 192.168.43.1.
Oct 17 16:14:26 computery systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
Oct 17 16:17:01 computery CRON[2981]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Oct 17 16:18:44 computery wpa_supplicant[835]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-35 noise=9999 txrate=72200
Oct 17 16:26:42 computery smartd[803]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel changed from 74 to 67
Oct 17 16:26:42 computery smartd[803]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 26 to 33
Oct 17 16:27:33 computery systemd[1]: Starting Message of the Day...
Oct 17 16:27:33 computery systemd[1]: motd-news.service: Succeeded.
Oct 17 16:27:33 computery systemd[1]: Finished Message of the Day.
Oct 17 16:30:01 computery CRON[3619]: (root) CMD ([ -x /etc/init.d/anacron ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d anacron start >/dev/null; fi)
Oct 17 16:30:19 computery systemd-timesyncd[724]: Initial synchronization to time server 91.189.89.199:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Oct 17 16:30:23 computery kernel: [ 2046.979816] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
Oct 17 16:30:23 computery kernel: [ 2046.982995] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
Oct 17 16:30:23 computery kernel: [ 2046.983590] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
Oct 17 16:30:26 computery systemd[1273]: Stopping Studio - session monitor...
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@Oct 17 19:00:31 computery systemd-modules-load[345]: Inserted module 'lp'
Oct 17 19:00:31 computery kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 5.4.0-48-lowlatency (buildd@lcy01-amd64-010) (gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2)) #52-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Thu Sep 10 11:51:50 UTC 2020 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-48.52-lowlatency 5.4.60)
Oct 17 19:00:31 computery kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-48-lowlatency root=UUID=acfebebf-4250-42c6-91a5-0e02a43f7f9d ro quiet splash vt.handoff=1
Oct 17 19:00:31 computery systemd-modules-load[345]: Inserted module 'ppdev'
Oct 17 19:00:31 computery kernel: [    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
Oct 17 19:00:31 computery kernel: [    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
Oct 17 19:00:31 computery kernel: [    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
```

EDIT: There are no SSD errors when tested with Smartmontools, so it's not a hardware fault.

Comment: One of your disks may be failing. Check your disks with SMART monitoring tools: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I diagnose Hang on Shutdown?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236476/how-do-i-diagnose-hang-on-shutdown)

Comment: A failing HDD is a possibility but it's a new machine.

Comment: Thanks Fadon Kadifeli. I used Smartmontools and there are no errors on the discs.

Answer (score -2):

I sometimes get this too as I am an avid user of Ubuntu, I find that using `sudo halt` in the terminal (of course you will have to log in to the terminal as root). This is the only effective way (other than the hard power off) that works for me.

Also possible duplicate of [How do I diagnose Hang on Shutdown?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236476/how-do-i-diagnose-hang-on-shutdown?rq=1)

Edit: after reading that post too, try `sudo shutdown -v -h now` to see if anything changes.

Comment: Computer says, shutdown: invalid option -- 'v'

Comment: Remove the -v. That is I am guessing for verbose output but it seems -v was either removed or outdated.

Comment: Thanks, it shuts down but still takes an age.

Comment: Are there any logs of the shutdown? That may be your best bet as to what is holding up the shut down for so long. I am glad at least the command worked (even if it did take an eternity).

Comment: Just had a look. It seems `less /var/log/syslog` and hitting CTRL + END keys will go to the end of the logs. Scroll up or search for keywords to see if you can find anything happening **after** the shutdown command is issued.

Comment: There are pages of activity after the shutdown command, as described in the OP.

Comment: Computer says, 'var/log/syslog': No such file or directory

Comment: probably because you missed the first `/`in front of var.

Comment: Whoops, thanks. Using <kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>PgDn</kbd> gets to the relevant time. Now to wait until the problem recurs...

Comment: No worries. Hope it fixes in the future.