# ubuntu 22.04 doesn't shutdown after I try to shutdown

Tags: shutdown, reboot

When I try to shutdown the laptop then It goes to blank screen showing my laptop name screen and then stop (not shutdown afterwards) - I mean laptop is not completely shutting down.
I need to press power button 5-10s to shut it down.

--same issue for restart too..

I tried previous posts answers but none of the work for my acer laptop.
Could you please tell me what to do?

Comment: [This can get you started](https://askubuntu.com/q/236476/). And then edit your question to add any additional info.  Also you can view more information about the last time you tried to shut down with something like `journalctl -b-1 -e` Alternatively, when this problem occurs, you can log into a console by pressing CTRL+ALT+F4 or CTRL+ALT+F5, type in your username and then enter your password when prompted to log in. From there, run `journalctl -b | grep -i error` and if that doesn't show anything interesting, then run the command with `sudo` for good measure to possibly reveal additional logs

Comment: can you deliberately explain what's happening i don't know what to do?

Comment: Right now, you can open a terminal and see your previous logs by running the following command: `journalctl -b-1 -e` Scroll to the end or look at the timestamps to view the last logs before or during shutdown. Furthermore, when you go to power down and if you encounter the problem again, instead of holding down the power button, you can view some logs instead by pressing CTRL+ALT+F4 or CTRL+ALT+F5 and then sign in with your username and password and then run the command: `journalctl -b | grep -i error`

Comment: If you see any errors that are time stamped around the time of shutdown, then please edit your question and paste the errors into your question so that we can see what's going on. This will help us determine the problem. It is best to copy and paste but if you can't, like if you're using the console, then try to write these down as best as possible. This is so we can google the error if it's not immediately apparent what the problem is.

Comment: FYI, CTRL+ALT+T will open a terminal for you.