# Ubuntu 22.04 can't shut down my laptop

Tags: 22.04, suspend, ssd, shutdown

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on external SSD and it works fine but when I try to shut down my laptop it doesn't completely shuts down, screen goes black but ventilators are keep working. It feels like it is trying to shut it down but it can't. It stays in limbo.
I left it like that for 5+ mins and force shut down it. Restart and Suspend work fine.

I have Windows 10 on laptop's hard drive and when on Windows it shuts down fine.

I assume it has to be with the fact that Ubuntu is on SSD and maybe it prevents from completely shut down laptop.
Did anybody have similar situation? How could I fix it? Thx!

Comment: See [this question and its answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236476/how-do-i-diagnose-hang-on-shutdown) for how to diagnose freeze at shutdown. Update your question with the entries from the `/var/log/kern.log` at the time of the shutdown attempt. Maybe that will give us some clue. You can also see the log as it happens by following the instructions of the top answer. When it gets stuck, take a picture. Add the picture to your question.

Comment: After the system comes up again, the terminal command `sudo journalctl   b -1 -ex` will show the system logs leading up to the crash /shutdown. You can look at other shutdowns by varying the `-b -1` option. If nothing stands out, suspect overheating or sudden power outage. Do `sudo journalctl  --list-boots`, read `man journalctl`. For more `journalctl` help, see my AskUbuntu profile (click on my username).