# Startup Screen stuck after login done

Tags: unity, 13.04, login-screen, desktop-background

Its a very new install of Raring (Ubuntu 13). My only OS on a HP dv2600 laptop with 2Gb RAM & 160Gb HDD.
My Login screen is stuck after the login is done. Its like it freezes after the login. **It now looks like my wallpaper.**

Please guide me irradiate this problem.

Comment: Use this guide to temporarily remove the splash screen and get more information about where does it get stuck: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6122/how-to-see-whats-going-on-during-shutdown

Comment: sorry, didn't help. I can use my system only the splash screen gets stuck.

Comment: Did you follow the guide to removed the splash screen or not?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was happening because of me halfway leaving the Gnome3 setup. Some files were casing and causing the problem. Now the problem is fixed. I am using Gnome now.