# Long startup time after power supply is changed

Tags: 14.04, boot

I have a deskop PC here running Ubuntu `14.04` and observer very long start up time - about 5 minutes.

If the `Ubuntu` is already started and I restarted it, it takes about 30 seconds to load. So the issue is connected only with OS start after the PC is shut down.

What is going on:

1. First, detecting the IDE devices is too slow (about 15 seconds)
2. Then, the Ubuntu background is shown for a few seconds.
3. After that a black screen is shown for 3-4 minutes.
4. Then the login interface is displayed

As I have known, this started when the PC power supply was changed. I have no idea if the man who changed it changed the BIOS settings, too.

Could anyone help me idendity if this is a BIOS settings issue, new hardware issue or OS issue?

Comment: Is the power supply the only change?  Are you booting with very large usb drives attached, for instance?

Comment: @TonyMartin I guess I know what you mean - sometimes if a external hard drive is attached and a bios HD space is made the boot time suffers. Anyway, in this case, there is no external drive. Also, note that if the OS is once loaded, after restarts the boot time is tiny.

Comment: I wonder if temporarily disabling `splash quiet` on boot might allow you to see where the boot process is lingering.  The top answer to this http://askubuntu.com/questions/6122/how-to-see-whats-going-on-during-shutdown shows how.