# Ubuntu 16 won't shut down and freezes

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, partitioning, shutdown, xps

I'm trying to learn linux and so I dual-boot Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS with Windows 10. Every time I shutdown Ubuntu I get some line of code:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p7: recovering journal
/dev/nvme0n1p7: Clearing orphaned inode ... 
/dev/nvme0n1p7: Clearing orphaned inode ... 
/dev/nvme0n1p7: Clean xxxx/xxxx files, xxxx/xxxx blocks
```

And it is just stuck there, I can't press any keys and have to cut the power.
My laptop:

- Dell XPS 15 9560

  - i7-7700HQ
  - 16GB RAM
  - 512 GB SSD

Comment: I think that this is actually a startup message,but the screen is never cleared, so you see it when you shut down

Comment: I have no idea, do you have any idea on how to get through it?

Comment: What is on that p7 partition. Can you show the result of `sudo fdisk -l` and `cat /etc/fstab`.

Comment: @WillemK I do belive it is Ubuntu itself, I can't check right now but I'm fairly sure.

Comment: In that case I suggest booting from Ubuntu Live USB/CD and perform an `e2fsck  /dev/nvme0n1p7`

Comment: @WillemK This is what I got  `e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)` - `/dev/nvme0n1p7: clean, 274598/3066000 files, 1881392/12259328 blocks`

Comment: Has the system been running/shutting without problems ?  If so, what has happened that might give us a clue ?

Comment: @WillemK It is running just fine and booting just fine, I have no clue to what caused this since I'm new to Linux. Before when it happened the lines of code that is in the main post appeared but the laptop shut down afterwards. Now it is just stuck on that screen and won't shut down without me holding the power... Thanks for using your time to help by the way :)

Comment: As you have a dual-boot system, edit the entry that you are booting and remove the `quiet` and `splash` arguments. See this example: `https://askubuntu.com/questions/6122/how-to-see-whats-going-on-during-shutdown`. When you have does this, you will get a lot of output on the text screen during boot and, most importantly in this case, during shutdown. Hopefully it tells you at which point the shutdown process gets stuck.

Comment: @WillemK this is the text i got: https://i.gyazo.com/0e850ae12c7e81ea434797e4acb72053.jpg

Comment: I also asked the question on reddit and got an awnser that said i should add acpi= noirq (`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=noirq quiet splash"`). This fixed the freeze during shutdown, and I now get to the Ubuntu screen with the dots before it shuts down. Is this solving the problem or just hiding it? And after I get to the Ubuntu screen it takes a long time until it has shut off, do you have any suggestion to why that happens?

Comment: It seems the JPG is showing the startup of your system, not the shutdown? Apparently the acpi setting has some effect, although I would not expect you to have to use it in an i7 laptop. What are the ACPI settings in the BIOS?  BTW.. does the issue return when you remove the acpi setting again. The link `https://wiki.mageia.org/en/How_to_set_up_kernel_options` gives more explanations on acpi.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58173/discussion-between-boomer-and-willem-k).